# connected phone arrangment in windows explorer - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, android, phone, rearrange

Windows10 - Windows Explorer with a USB connect Android (Samsung)

not a major issue, it's really a small thing, but would be nicer having the phone not group up in the middle of "documents" "pictures" etc..

Anyway, can set it, that the phone shows up below the hard drives? or directly under "this PC"?

[image]

yes, could rename my phone, that it starts with an "A". then it would be on top, but that is just cheating.

anybody an idee?